# require_once in Moodle (Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...)

Tags: php, require-once

I am trying to write an enrol plugin for moodle and therefor I need the functions of the /moodle/enrol/cohort/lib.php file.

But when I try

```
global $CFG;

require_once($CFG->dirroot . '../lib.php');
```

it gives me

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/moodle/enrol/cohort/enrol_module/result.php on line 20
```

line 20 is

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '../lib.php');
```

The Path should be correct. Can someone tell me what is responsible for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chris Lear thanks, you were right:) I included the file where $CFG is set:

```
require_once('../../../config.php');
```

the second require part was wrong, too

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/enrol/cohort/lib.php');

global $CFG;
```

Comment: After you require config.php, you no longer need to set $CFG as a global variable, unless you're in a function.